# Not able to access the REST services hosted on AWS EC2 to local WAMP server

Tags: web-services, amazon-ec2, wamp, connectivity, pimcore

I have deployed the Pimcore DAM app on Amazon EC2 instance. The Pimcore product offers REST services to integrate it with PHP which I am able to access successfully from the POSTMAN client but the same services are not working when I am trying to access it from my local WAMP server through cURL request. It's giving me the below error -

"cURL Error #:Failed to connect to 13.58.32.47 port 80: Timed out" [13.58.32.47 - Public IP of the EC2 instance]

Could you please help me in order to resolve this connectivity issue?

Inbound Rules -   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJIW8.png
Outbound Rules - [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ACYF.png

Thanks & Regards,
Anup

Comment: So your POSTMAN client and your local WAMP servers I assume are running on different systems?  Have you investigated the usual, security group and subnet NACL configurations in your AWS environment?

Comment: Hi Ashaman, No my POSTMAN client and local WAMP server are running on the same system. Security groups are as below -

Comment: The security group information didn't come through. Instead of adding it as a comment, please edit your question and include both the security group and subnet NACL information.

Comment: Attached the screenshots of the Inbound and Outbound Rules.